# Detect empty, new tab openings in Google Chrome

Tags: url, google-chrome-extension, tabs, manifest, browser-history

I just published a Google Chrome extension which loads background images into new, empty tabs. The plugin is found here in the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pixabay-tab-background-im/icmjpejeoaaooefghfokacdlnobioldb).

For detecting new and empty tabs, I need to ask for "tab" permissions in the extension's `manifest.json`. This, however, gives the extension the permission to read the browser's history. Not all users will want this and we don't actually need it. Is there a way to detect empty tabs without this permission requirement? Currently our check looks like this:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
    if (changeInfo.status == "loading" && tab.url == 'chrome://newtab/')
    { /* load background into tab */ }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to customize the new tab page you should add this to your manifest:

```
"chrome_url_overrides": {
   "newtab": "newtab.html"
}
```

Then place the script you are currently injecting into new tab pages as a `<script>` tag in the newtab.html file. That won't cause that permission message.

Comment: I do exactly that, but the code is yet called even if the tab is opened with a URL in place. But I only need to run this code for empty tabs.

Comment: If you do the above you won't need to inject a script into the new tab page, you'll be able to add a reference to it in the `newtab.html` file. That means it will only appear when the regular new tab page appears.

Comment: That may work. I'll check that later. I'm not sure if the newtab.html is also temporarily loaded when a URL is present ... thanks in advance!